# Add custom button to Galleria

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleria

I want to add a 'Buy Now' button to Galleria which will trigger adding the image to a visitors cart.

I have the cart code already set up but I am struggling to figure out how to add the custom button to Galleria.

I am currently using the classic theme and have added the image into the map.png. I can set up the CSS no problem but can't figure out how to code the extension to Galleria.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could attach a buy url to the data object and then assign the url to the button on the [image event](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/api/events/#image):

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src="one.jpg">
  <a href="buyone.html">Buy now</a>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="two.jpg">
  <a href="buytwo.html">Buy now</a>
</div>
```

CSS (example, style as you wish)

```
.galleria-button {
    z-index:3;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
  dataConfig: function(img) {
    // return a new buylink key that points to the 
    // next anchor’s href attribute
    return { buylink: $(img).next().attr('href') }; 
  },
  extend: function() {

    // the current buy link
    var buy;

    // create the button and append it
    this.addElement('button').appendChild('container','button');

    // Add text & click event using jQuery
    this.$('button').text('Buy now').click(function() {
        window.location = buy;
    });

    // change the buy link on image
    this.bind('image', function(e) {
      buy = this.getData(e.index).buylink;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should consider building [your own theme](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/themes/creating_a_theme/). Galleria is 'extensively extendable', and you can add your cart button in the `init` function of your theme

Comment: Was hoping to avoid this by adapting an existing theme. Planned to use the 'Twelve' theme eventually, but wanted to adapt the classic theme to get me started. Am currently wading through the Galleria source to try and add it in there. Think the appendChild method is where i need to be...